# How to display two different image.png depending on users gender?

Tags: javascript, html, image, onload, getelementsbytagname

I have a little problem, I would like to display two different images (maleuser.png, femaleuser.png) depending on user gender. I created HTML page, MySQL table. oneuserpage.html displaying data from a base, I made a position for the image o page.

And now how to create a text dependency (male, female) with a picture with JavaScript?

Comment: Please share the html page in a code sample, this way any variables are much more easily collaborated with. (Also, this is not meant to be saucy, could you let the user select what gender they want to display with a drop down with more than two options?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have variable img (`HTMLImageElement` — your image) and gender (if gender equals "male" or "female"): `img.src = gender + "user.png";`. Another gender format:

```js
img.src = (gender == yourMaleSyntax) ? "maleuser.png" : "femaleuser.png";
```

I recommend first syntax.
Please try it and check my answer as best.

Answer (score 0):

First we have to number of rows from the database table with following code: late's say your page is try.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
?>
```

In same php page (try.php), below above code we have to create html table that will contain all the data / rows that we got from execution of above query

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th> Username </th>
      <th> email </th>
      <th> phone</th>
      <th> gender photo</th>
    </tr>
<?php
if($result){    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $fetchuser = $row['uname'];
        $fetchmail = $row['uemail'];
        $fetchpass = $row['upassword'];
        $fetchgender = $row['ugender'];

?>  
<tr>
    <tr> 
        <td><?php echo $fetchuser;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetchmail;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fetchpass;?></td>
        <td>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var gender = "<?php echo $fetchgender;?>";
        if(gender==0){
            document.write('<img src="maleuser.png" alt="Male"/>');
        }else{
            document.write('<img src="maleuser.png" alt="Female"/>');
        }
        </script>
        </td>

    </tr>   
<?php
   }
 }

else{

}
?>
</table>
```

I have tasted and it works! hope it would be helpful to you and others as well.  Thank You.